# Save form data to collection using meteor methods

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Using Meteor I'm trying to capture and save some data (name, email and age) using a form. This data should be saved in a new Meteor collection "Subscribers". My code as follows:

**Template Events** (client\views\subscribe_form\subscribe_form.js)

```
Template.Subscribe.events({ 
    'submit form#subscribe-form': function(event){
        // Prevent default browser form submit
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get values from the form
        var subName = $('form#subscribe-form [name=subscribe-name]').val();
        var subEmail = $('form#subscribe-form [name=subscribe-email]').val();
        var subAge = $('form#subscribe-form [name=subscribe-age]').val();

        let subscriberData = {
            name: subName,
            email: subEmail,
            age: subAge,
            createdAt: new Date()
        };

        // Insert subscriber into the collection
        Meteor.call('SubscribeNow', subscriberData, function(error, result){
            if(error){
                // Output error if subscription fails
                console.log(error.reason);
            } else {
                // Success
                console.log("Subscription successful");
                console.log(subscriberData);
                console.log( Subscribers.find() );
            }
        });
    },
});
```

**Server side** (server\collections\subscribers.js)

```
var Subscribers = new Meteor.Collection('subscribers');

Subscribers.allow({
    insert: function(){
        return true;
    }
});

Meteor.methods({
    'SubscribeNow': function (subscriberData) {
        //check(subscriberData, String);

        try {
            // Any security checks, such as logged-in user, validating data, etc.
            Subscribers.insert(subscriberData);
        } catch (error) {
            // error handling, just throw an error from here and handle it on client
            if (badThing) {
                throw new Meteor.Error('bad-thing', 'A bad thing happened.');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now when I add some data to the form and click the submit button it goes through the success console.log message, the data is picked-up properly but whenever I try to query the collection it won't show anything at all.

I tried looking for the data in the collection using a simple template I created to list the Subscribers collection in a table, also with Meteor Toys and via `console.log( Subscribers.find() );` but no luck. It seems the forms goes through but the data is not saved in the collection.

[image]

Also, *autopublish* and *insecure* are removed.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I'm still pretty new to everything Meteor so it might be something obvious I'm missing here.

Let me know if you need to see more of the code. Finally, any suggestions for code improvement (structuring or such) are welcome.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: A couple of quick notes: 1. Don't simply `allow` the direct insertion to the collection. It is not required for methods on the server and allows any user to insert arbitrary data into the collection. 2. You don't normally have access to all of the DB from the client side. That's what pub/sub is for. If you wish to know what data is stored on the server, query the database directly (using `meteor shell`, `meteor mongo` or any gui/cli tool that allows you to directly access the DB). 3. validate the user input on the server.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just used `meteor mongo` to query the data and everything is there. So it must be something wrong in listing bit. I'll look into it. Thanks for the tip. Furthermore, you said not to simply allow the direct insertion to the collection. What would be the best approach in my case? The form is basically a newsletter sort to say, so the form is public, everyone can submit their info. Now in the back-end I just simply want to list the 'subscribers'. What would you recommend for this scenario? I would really appreciate an example. Also if you could elaborate on (2) please.

Comment: For (2) check out publications and subscriptions. Read [The Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/) for a lot more info. Since you are using a method, you can validate the user input before inserting it to the database. You probably don't want to allow just anyone to store anything in your collection (someone can use their browser's console to call your methods with arbitrary data).

Answer (score 1):

So from your question and comments you've added to your question, the `Subscribers` collection data is being saved properly (you've verified this using `meteor mongo`), but you can't retrieve the data using `Subscribers.find()`. Since you've removed the `autopublish` package, you'll have to make sure you're subscribing to a publication that's responsible for pushing your `Subscribers` data from the server to the client. For example:

**/server/publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('allSubscribers', function () {
  return Subscribers.find();
});
```

**/client/some_template.js**

```
Template.someTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  this.subscribe('allSubscribers');
});
...
```

After you've subscribed to your data, you can then run `Subscribers.find()` client side, and have data returned.

For more information, see the [Publications and Data Loading](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html) section of the Meteor Guide.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I've managed to sort out the listing as well and it's working fine. I'm just adding now the validation before insert as per MasterAM's suggestion. Anything else I should consider for a public form like this? I want to make it as secure as possible for this scenario.